# Why I don't see a visionOS plugin in Unity XR Plugin Management window?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visionos

I'm trying to build visionOS project according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQmplq9ycYY&t=1s&ab_channel=Unity) guideline.

1. I use Unity 2022.3.10f1, that is 2022.3.5f1+ according to [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/visionOS.html) manual. I use Unity Pro license.
2. I've installed visionOS editor build target and set it as my project build target and added a scene.
   [image]
3. I've installed Unity XR Plugin management plugin.
4. I also set Beta channel to Unity Hub(don't know if it is important).

And as result I have visionOS tab in the Unity XR Plugins Management window but there is no visionOS plugin available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unity Pro, Unity Enterprise, or Unity Industry, but not Unity Personal.

Comment: I have Unity Pro

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).